# How to send message to a telegram bot using telebot api or telegram api

Tags: node.js, telegram, webhooks, telebot

I currently have created a bot in telegram and am using it to perform some action whenever a msg is sent to the bot uisng the telebot api. I now am creating a new app where my back end gets the data from a webhook and I want to directly send that data to the bot after which the bot will perform the pre defined task on it. Is it possible ?. How can I do it?. Links to any guides would also be helpful.

so far I have only ever replied to msg received to the bot direct from the telebot api an have never have sent a msg to the bot from my back end. From what I read you need to get the id of user you want to send msg to how can I get the id for a bot and send data to that id directly.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

```
import express from 'express';
import TeleBot from 'telebot';

const bot = new TeleBot(process.env.BOT_TOKEN);

bot.on('/start', async (msg) => {
  const chatId = msg.chat.id;
  await bot.sendMessage(chatId, 'Hello world!');
});

const app = express();

app.use(express.json());

app.post('/webhook', (req, res) => {
  const chatId = process.env.BOT_CHAT_ID;
  const message = req.body.message;

  bot.sendMessage(chatId, message);

  res.send('Message sent to bot!');
});

const port = process.env.PORT || 3000;

app.listen(port, () => {
  console.log(`Server listening on port ${port}`);
});
```

does this code help?